# I am facing an error during my signed APK in android

Tags: flutter, apk

I am working on flutter and when I build signed Apk for android to upload on plays tore error occurred during build

Type io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin is defined multiple times: C:\tm_mobile_app\build\firebase_core\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\release\classes.jar:io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.class, C:\tm_mobile_app\build\app\intermediates\javac\release\classes\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.class

I have remove from everywhere but still facing issue